# Evaluate the uniform and the normal convergence of the series of functions $\sum \frac{x}{(1 + x^2)^n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

> A series of functions with the general term $ f_n(x) $ defined as:
> $$ f_n(x) = \frac{x}{(1 + x^2)^n} \space , \space  x \geq 0  $$
>
> 1. Evalute the uniform and normal convergence of the series $\sum_{n = 1}^{+ \infty} \frac{x}{(1 + x^2)^n} $ on $\mathbb{R}^+$
> 2. Prove that the series have normal convergence on $[a, + \infty[$ with $ a > 0 $
> 3. Is the series uniformally convergent on $[0,1]$?

---

We have for all $ x \geq 0 $:

$$ f_n'(x) = \frac{(1 + x)^{n - 1}[1 + (1 - 2n)x^2]}{(1 + x^2)^{2n}} = 0 \iff x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2n - 1}} $$

and for all $ x \geq 0 $ :

$$ | f_n(x) | \leq f_n( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2n - 1}} ) = \frac{\sqrt{2n - 1}}{2^n (2n - 1) (1 + n)^n} \leq \frac{1}{2^n} $$

Since $ \sum \frac{1}{2^n} $ is convergent, then $ \sum f_n $ have normal convergence on $[0, + \infty[$.

2. From this question, I think that $ \sum f_n $ have normal convergent on the interval $[a, + \infty[$ only, and not on $ [0, + \infty[ $
3. From what I found in question 1, the series have normal convergence on $ [0, + \infty[ $, which implies uniform convergence on the interval $ [0,1] $

What am I missing? Thank you.

Comment: For each $n\geq 1$ and $x>0$ define $S_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{x}{(x^2+1)^k}$. It's not hard to show that $S_n(x)$ has the following closed form: $$S_n(x)=\frac{1}{x}\cdot \Bigg[1-\frac{1}{(x^2+1)^n}\Bigg]$$ It's also evident that $\{S_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges pointwise to $S(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ on $(0,\infty)$. However, we have for any $n\in \mathbb{N}$ that $$\sup_{x\in (0,\infty)}|S_n(x)-S(x)|=\sup_{x\in (0,\infty)}\frac{1}{(x^2+1)^n}=1$$ This implies the convergence to $\frac{1}{x}$ is *not* uniform on $(0,\infty)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The series $\sum_{n = 1}^{+ \infty} \frac{x}{(1 + x^2)^n}$ is a geometric series.

$$
\sum_{n = 1}^{+ \infty} \frac{x}{(1 + x^2)^n} =
x \sum_{n = 1}^{+ \infty} \left(\frac{1}{1 + x^2}\right)^n
$$
Geometric series have a remainder that is explicit. You can actually compute the sum of the series for all $x>0$. Moreover convergence of the series $\sum y^n$, $ y= 1/(1+x^2)$, is normal on any interval $y 
\in [0, a]$ with $a<1$, as is seen by bounding $y$ by $a$.

So the series $\sum_{n = 1}^{+ \infty} \frac{x}{(1 + x^2)^n}$ is normally convergent on all intervals $[a,\infty)$ for $a>0$.

**EDIT:**
But it is not convergent on $[0,\infty)$.
To show that, we need to find the maximal value of $x \mapsto {x(1+x^2)^{-n}}$ on this interval.

I let you find this maximum by differentiating this function. It is attained in $x= {1\over \sqrt{2n-1}}$. The value of the maximum is
${1\over \sqrt{2n-1}} {1\over (1+ {1\over 2n-1})^n}$.

$$ 
\sup\{x(1+x^2)^{-n} \mid x\in [0,\infty[\} = {1\over \sqrt{2n-1}} {1\over (1+ {1\over 2n-1})^n} \sim C/\sqrt{n}
$$
for some constant $C$. This is the general term of a divergent series.
$$
\sum \left\|x(1+x^2)^{-n}\right\|_\infty = +\infty.
$$

Comment: The convergence is normal for all $ x > 0$ ? Why are we asked to show that we have the normal convergence on the interval $ [a, + \infty[ $? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: The series \sum y^n converges normally on all intervals $[0,a]$ with $a<1$. It does not converge normally on the interval $[0,1]$. In fact it does not even converge for $y=1$.

Comment: For our series of functions: $\sum f_n(x) = \frac{x}{(1 + x^2)^n}$, it is normally convergent for all $ x \geq 0$. Right?

Comment: No, it is not normally convergent on $[0,\infty[$. I have edited my answer to carry the computation of the series of the norms.

Comment: I also suggest that you compute explicitely the limit of the series. You will see that it is not continuous at zero. Hence the convergence can't be uniform since uniform convergence implies continuity of the limit. Let me also recall the fact that normal convergence implies uniform convergence.

Comment: I understand now why the series is not uniformally convergent, I am having trouble with the normal convergence, what do you mean $y$ ? We have for all $ x \in \mathbb{R}^+: \frac{1}{1 + x^2} \leq 1$, I don't see why $x$ has to be greater than $a$ for the convergence to be normal. What am I missing?

Comment: See my edit. I have computed explicitely the series of the uniform norms. Normal convergence means that this series converges. I have taken $y = 1/(1+x^2)$ to make clearer that this is a geometric series.

Comment: I understand it! To have $ y < 1 $ we need to have $ x > 0 $. Answer accepted, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

For $x=0$, the sum converges to $\sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n(0)=0$.

For $x>0$, we have

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n(x)$ = $x \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{1+x^2}\right)^n$
where the expression in parentheses is strictly smaller than 1 for $x>0$, so we have a geometric sum
which equals $x \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{1+x^2}}=\frac{1+x^2}{x}=:F(x)$ with
$F(x)\rightarrow \infty$ as $x\rightarrow 0^+$

So your function series does not uniformly converge on $[0,a]$ for any $a>0$ but it may be (and is by your criteria) on $[a,\infty)$ for all $a>0$.

(EDIT: above derivation is for sum starting at $n=0$, but same argument for sum starting at $n=1$)

EDIT 2: the above product of $x$ with a geometric series illustrates that formally, for $x=0$, we have a form "$0\times \infty$", so we know, we have to be careful at $x=0$

Answer (score 3):

The series is not uniformly convergent for $x \in[0,1]$. A typical approach to showing this (without knowing the sum in closed form) is

$$\tag{*}\sup_{x \in [0,1]}\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{x}{(1+x^2)^k}\right| = \sup_{x \in [0,1]}\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{x}{(1+x^2)^k}\geqslant \sup_{x \in [0,1]}\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} \frac{x}{(1+x^2)^k}\\ \geqslant\sup_{x \in [0,1]}n \cdot \frac{x}{(1+x^2)^{2n}}\geqslant n \cdot \frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}{\left(1 + \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^2\right)^{2n}}= \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\left(1+ \frac{1}{n}\right)^{2n}}$$

Since $\left(1+ \frac{1}{n}\right)^{2n} \to e^2$ as $n \to \infty$, the RHS of (*) tends to $+\infty$, and, thus,

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sup_{x \in [0,1]}\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{x}{(1+x^2)^k}\right|\neq 0$$